# How to get a list of stored notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, uilocalnotification

Implemented notification using the flutter local notification plugin. Is there any way to get the list of all the stored notification?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.